# What make $f_n\circ g_n \to f\circ g $ uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

> Assume that $f_n,g_n$ are continuous and $f_n\to f$ uniformly, $g_n\to g$ uniformly. I know that $f_n\circ g_n$ does not converge to $f\circ g$ uniformly  in general. But what sort of conditions to make $f_n\circ g_n  \to f\circ g$ uniformly? How about boundedness of $f_n$ and $g_n$? how about if $f_n$ and $g_n$ are differentiable?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One sufficient condition is $f$ to be uniformly continuous since $$\|f_n(g_n(x))-f(g(x))\|\leqslant\|f_n(g_n(x))-f(g_n(x))\|+\|f(g_n(x))-f(g(x))\|.$$